# Bootstrap pagination for buttons

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I like the look of the [pagination hyperlinks in Twitter Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#sizing), but in my case they have to be button type="submit".

Is there a way to style buttons using the pagination look?

Comment: what technology do you use? asp.net? php?

Comment: @eminach how would that be important?

Comment: if you are using asp.net you can put runat="server"

Comment: Else, you can handle this link click, by jQuery

Comment: The question is about css styles, not about jquery or anything else. Am I wrong?

Comment: Yes, HTML and CSS with Twitter Bootstrap.

Comment: @Phillip, did you tried `class="btn btn-default"`? It looks almost the same, except the for the font color, which you can change easily

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the classes `btn` and `btn-default`, and the button will look like almost the same as the pagination links, except for the color, which you can change with a class.

Check [this](https://jsfiddle.net/cbe11wh7/) jsfiddle for an example.

EDIT:

You can use a  wrapper with `class="btn-group"` if you have several buttons. Like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/cbe11wh7/4/)

Comment: It doesn't look quite right yet. (There's a gap between the buttons). [See this update](https://jsfiddle.net/cbe11wh7/2/).

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get you needed several buttons. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to turn the html  tags into buttons using the "btn-toolbar" and "btn-group" tags like so:

```
<div class="btn-toolbar" role="toolbar" style="margin: 0;">
    <div class="btn-group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default color-blue"><i class="fa fa-fast-backward"></i></button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default color-blue"><i class="fa fa-step-backward"></i></button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default text-faded">1 of 12</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default color-blue"><i class="fa fa-step-forward"></i></button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default color-blue"><i class="fa fa-fast-forward"></i></button>
    </div>
</div>
```

That is the closest you will get to use pagination and buttons on a .Net application.